# Cannot find the answer after my research, help me with mysql

Tags: php

The Error is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':rafli_namaUser, :rafli_username, :rafli_password)' at line 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\rafli_kasir\rafli_register.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\rafli_kasir\rafli_register.php(16): mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO raf...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\rafli_kasir\rafli_register.php on line 16

cannot find any solution after research, this is my code:

```
<?php
require_once("rafli_koneksi.php");
if(isset($_POST['rafli_register'])){
    $rafli_namaUser = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rafli_namaUser', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $rafli_username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'rafli_username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $rafli_password = password_hash($_POST["rafli_password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO rafli_user (rafli_namaUser, rafli_username, rafli_password) 
            VALUES (:rafli_namaUser, :rafli_username, :rafli_password)";
    $stmt = $rafli_conn->prepare($sql);
    $params = array(
        ":rafli_namaUser" => $rafli_namaUser,
        ":rafli_username" => $rafli_username,
        ":rafli_password" => $rafli_password
    );
    $saved = $stmt->execute($params);
    if($saved) header("Location: rafli_login.php");
}
?>
```

rafli_koneksi.php

```
<?php

$rafli_host = "localhost";
$rafli_username = "root";
$rafli_password = "";
$rafli_database = "rafli_kasir";
$rafli_conn = new mysqli( $rafli_host, $rafli_username, $rafli_password, $rafli_database );
    echo 'Gagal terhubung ke database';
} else {
    // Koneksi berhasil
}
```

?>

Comment: what line does return the error?

Comment: Tune up your [MySQL error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/mysqli-fetch-assoc-expects-parameter-call-to-a-member-function-bind-param) to get feedback on what's failing.

Comment: this part  `$_POST["rafli_password"]` you are grabbing field value raw which means user are allowed to use Space character only for there password unless you validate it before hand ( it would be bad if user decided to press the spacebar 6x and it accept it as password )

Comment: Also in future, PLEASE post the complete error message and not a summary. Also please post the error in the question and not as the title

Comment: @EmmaMarshall Actually 6 spaces generates a perfectly usable hash :) Undiscernable from any other hash. But it would be useful to enforce certain requirements I agree

Comment: @PavelJanicek its line 15 where $saved = $stmt->execute($params);

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `rafli_koneksi.php` please

Comment: SO you mixed up the `PDO` and `MYSQLI_` extensions. They are not the same thing at all. Use `?` instead and [READ THE MANUAL pages about the mysqli_ extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) Specially the `bind_param()` section

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have updated the question, please check it

Comment: I have added a comment please read that and then read the manual

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to define `$rafli_conn` in this piece of code?

`bool` means `Boolean`, i.e. true or false.

You set `$stmt = $rafli_conn->prepare($sql);` and later it says that you cannot call `->execute()` on a bool — so there is a high likelihood that `$stmt` is returning `false`.

Can you `print_r($stmt)` and test what its value is? Once you have that working, you should be fine.

Comment: `$stmt = $rafli_conn->prepare($sql);` returns `false` because `$rafli_conn` is not defined anywhere. **Edit** Yup, I entered that comment before your edit :)]

Comment: I'm guessing it's coming from `require_once("rafli_koneksi.php");`.

Comment: @PavelJanicek you were too quick for me!

Comment: If `$rafli_conn` didnt exist, the error would be from the `prepare` line and would be `Warning: Undefined variable $rafli_conn`

Comment: @RiggsFolly might that change depending on the level of error reporting you have set?

Comment: when i add print_r($stmt) nothing showed up

Comment: what happens if you add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL)` before your code on this page?

Comment: OP is using PDO, well at least the INSERT using named parameters insinuates that, so `mysqli_` functions wont help

Comment: @Djave Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':rafli_namaUser, :rafli_username, :rafli_password)' at line 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\rafli_kasir\rafli_register.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\rafli_kasir\rafli_register.php(16): mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO raf...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\rafli_kasir\rafli_register.php on line 16

Comment: **Well now we know what the issue is** You cannot use NAMED PARAMETERS when using the `MYSQLI_` database extension.